# Local storage issue in HTML 5 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am making a checklist app with Phonegap but it debugs in a browser too as they both use web technologies. Anyway, I am having a problem with using the HTML 5 local storage. Perhaps my code is broken, or I am using it wrong. When ever I refresh the page or exit out/come back the data is gone.

Appreciate any help :^)

**I tested it on my live domain** as well as locally but both do not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <script>
            $(function() {
              var arr = [];
              var i;
              $("button").click(function() {
                arr.push($(":text").val());
                $(":text").val("");
                localStorage.setItem("item" + arr.length, arr[arr.length - 1]);
                $("#x").append(localStorage.getItem("item" + arr.length) + "<br>");
              })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Alex</h1>
            <input type="text" id="item" placeholder="Enter an item">
            <button id="add">Add Item</button>
            <br>
            <div id="x"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oops.. My bad.. Thanks @Quentin.. :)

Comment: Your code seems to be working [here](https://jsbin.com/womumukuwu/edit?html,js,output). What is the exact problem? Is it the repetition of array items?

Comment: @anu It still doesn't save at all, if it isn't my code, maybe its something else?

Answer (score 1):

As was said - the data is persisted and saved correctly.

However the logic is incorrect and overrides all the elements in the localStorage (first element overrides the first, second overrides the first two, third overrides the first three, etc.). Perhaps this is what masks the issue? :)

To be frank, I don't the the logic of running in loop and overriding all existing with the last item (and writing it to the list on the screen each time)...

Comment: "Perhaps my code is broken, or I am using it wrong", "Appreciate any help" - this is by OP. However, I appreciate the remark and will take care.

Comment: @st2rseeker yes the logic is bad but is that what is causing the saving problem? the data is not persisting for me. any tips on how I should test it, should I try anything? Thanks

Comment: @st2rseeker I fixed the logic, it works now but without the saving stuff